# Subversion (svn) integration with Apache?

Tags: apache, svn, integration

I am running a website on my server with Apache, and I have also setup SVN with Apache.

The problem arises when I make changes in httpd.conf to setup SVN and restart Apache. It starts to serve files as SVN, but it stops my website. Then every user can see my source code.

I want to make my server as development server and production server. How can I run Apache for SVN and host my website?

Answer (score 3):

First install `dav svn`:

```
apt-get install libapache2-svn

root@example:/var# mkdir svn
root@example:/var# cd svn
root@example:/var/svn# svnadmin create repo

a2enmod dav_svn
```

Change permissions for Apache:

```
chown -R root.www-data /var/svn
chmod -R g+rw /var/svn
```

Add the repository to a virtual host

```
<Location /svn/myrepo>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /var/svn/repo

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "My Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd

  Require valid-user
</Location>

htpasswd2 /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passw user
```

Comment: thanks khemikal, I am using Windows Server. I have make changes in httpd.conf like this
<VirtualHost svn.mydomain.com:80>
 ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
 DocumentRoot C:/svn/
 ServerName svn.mydomain.com
 ServerAlias svn
  <Location />
        DAV svn
        SVNPath C:/svn/
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "my repo"
        AuthUserFile passwd
  </Location>
 </VirtualHost>

but when I try to open svn.mydomain.com in my browser then I get error "Server not found". Any idea how can I achieve this